# can't find FingerPaint sample

Tags: android, graphics

I study android graphics and i faced to strange problem:
I found a lot of mentions of "FingerPaint" sample, but i can't find it in sample folder.

There is just 47 sample projects, and no one about graphics.

How can I download this sample? I follow to this instructions
[link](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10):

If you downloaded the "SDK Samples" in Android's SDK Manager you can find `FingerPaint.java` on your hard drive:

```
<sdk>\samples\android-<version>\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics
```

---

If you want to run this app in Eclipse, select:

```
New > Other... > Android > Android Sample Project
```

Then choose an appropriate build target and select the `ApiDemos` project.

Answer (score 1):

Which sample you want to download? Or you have problem in downloading sample from sdk?
If you want to download sample from sdk then 
Go on the new android project window there should be three options:

1. Create new project in workspace
2. Create project from existing source
3. Create project from existing sample
   (The third one is a bit hidden, as there is a text box, and check box below the second item before the third one.

Select #3, then select the api level you want the sample for (in the list below), then you can select a sample from the now non-grayed out list.